# Reference SUBMANIFOLDS OF R^N

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, compact-manifolds

Is there any good reference that makes the theory of manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Especially area, coarea formulae, curvatures for submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^N$, Differentiability, Vector fields, Lie brackets, Operators, Surface theory, operators, tensor, forms, bundles...and all the staff.

It is above my level to understand manifold theory in abstract context from a place on...

Comment: Introduction to smooth manifolds by Lee is a standard recommendation. Have you checked it out?